# PyQt5, как получить источник enterEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt5, события, pyside2, pyside6

В приложении, написанном на Python с использование PyQt5 есть кнопка.

```
someButton = QPushButton(objectName='button1')
```

На эту кнопку назначен ивент `enterEvent`, срабатывающий когда курсор наводится на эту кнопку

```
def some_func(event):
    print('Some text')


someButton.enterEvent = some_func
```

Но что если таких кнопок несколько и я хочу получить информацию о том, какая кнопка послужила триггером ивента? Если бы это был сигнал вроде `clicked`, то я мог бы легко получить такое.

```
def some_func():
    print(self.sender())

someButton.clicked.connect(some_func)
```

Но для `enterEvent` такое не работает, `self.sender()` возвращает `None`

Может виджет-триггер можно как-то получить из event, или же как-то иначе подключить `enterEvent`?

Желательно без переопределения кнопки в отдельный класс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом случае на помощь к вам придет [lambda](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/):

```py
def func(event: QEnterEvent, sender: QPushButton):
    print('Event:', event)
    print('Sender:', sender.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    # ...

    button = QPushButton("Button 1")
    button.enterEvent = lambda e, btn=button: func(e, sender=btn) # Можно и без sender=, но для наглядности
    button.show()

    button = QPushButton("Button 2")
    button.enterEvent = lambda e, btn=button: func(e, sender=btn)
    button.show()

    button = QPushButton("Button 3")
    button.enterEvent = lambda e, btn=button: func(e, sender=btn)
    button.show()

    button = QPushButton("Button 4")
    button.enterEvent = lambda e, btn=button: func(e, sender=btn)
    button.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть два варианта.

Согласно документации:

> [virtual protected] void QWidget::enterEvent(QEvent *event)
>
> Этот обработчик событий может быть повторно реализован **в подклассе**
> для приема событий вxода в виджет, которые передаются в параметре события.
> Событие отправляется виджету, когда курсор мыши входит в виджет.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Button(QPushButton):    
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setText(f"Кнопка {num}")
        self.setObjectName(f"button{num}")
        
    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        print(f'leaveEvent: {self.text()}')
        
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print(f'enterEvent: {self.text()}')


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        for i in range(5):
            btn = Button(i+1)
            layout.addWidget(btn)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

Другой вариант, который используется в практике - это установка фильтра событий.

> void QObject::installEventFilter(QObject *filterObj)
>
> Устанавливает фильтр событий filterObj на этот объект.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        for i in range(5):
            btn = QPushButton(f"Кнопка {i+1}", objectName=f"button{i+1}")
            btn.installEventFilter(self)
            layout.addWidget(btn)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            print(f'QEvent.Leave: obj={obj.text()}, {obj.objectName()}') 
            return True
        elif event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            print(f'\nQEvent.Enter: obj={obj.text()}, {obj.objectName()}')
            return True        
  
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]